# Change displayconfiguration with autolisp script

Tags: autolisp

I'm trying to call the displaymanager configuration selection, by an autolisp command, but it doesn't work.

When I call the command DISPLAYCONFIGSETCURRENT directly from the command line, it works! But in a autolisp script, it doesn't work and I can't figure it out..

My goal is, to call the DISPLAYCONFIGSETCURRENT and then preset my configuration, so it changes in one click or command.

Here is my code, and thanks in advance, every help is appreciated.

```
(defun c:changeConfig()
    (setq config "Standard")
    (command "DISPLAYCONFIGSETCURRENT" config)
(princ)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution my self :D

Here is my code:

```
(defun c:changeConfig()
    (setq config "myDisplay")
    (command "-AecDisplayConfigSetCurrent" config)
(princ)
)
```